# What is the current version of final Microsoft Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: version, visual-studio-2013, rtm

Does anyone know what is the current version of final Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (the one that was released for sale)?

Answer (score 6):

The RTM version that you can download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) is:

Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

[image]

Comment: The official version for .NET framework seems to be 4.5.50938.18408 (checked today from Microsoft downloads).
Where did you get yours?

Comment: @picrap I get 4.5.51641 on Windows 8.1 RTM x64. On Windows 7 I also have 4.5.50938.

Comment: OK I'm on Windows 8, this explains the difference.

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out which "update" of Visual Studio they've got, this might help: http://geekswithblogs.net/terje/archive/2013/12/14/visual-studio-and-tfs-2013-list-of-product-updates-part.aspx

Answer (score 0):

the 1 that i download yesterday from https://www.dreamspark.com/ (a website from microsoft where students can download some of there software) was still the rc

edit
Visual Studio Professional 2013 final version will be available on October 31st